# Simplifying $\frac{1}{x^4+4x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve this problem on my own and it involves simplifying the expression in the title.

In the solutions it says it's this:

$$\frac{1}{x^4+4x^2} = \frac{1}{4}\Biggl[\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+4}\Biggr]$$

But I can't for the life of me figure out where the 1/4 came from. Or exactly how they got to this answer...

Comment: Have you ever learnt partial fractions? This is precisely it.

Answer (score 4):

We can write the fraction as,
$$\frac{1}{x^4 +4x^2} = \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{4}{x^2(x^2+4)}$$
The fraction $\frac{4}{x^2(x^2+4)}$ can be written as..

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{4}{x^2(x^2+4)}=\frac{1}{4}\Biggl[\frac{(x^2+4)-x^2}{x^2(x^2+4)}\Biggr]\\
=\frac{1}{4}\Biggl[\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+4}\Biggr]
\end{align}
Understand?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Writing $$\frac{1}{x^2(x^2+4)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+4}$$ and compute the real numbers $$A,B,C,D$$